# Conditional formatting on Excel 2010

Tags: excel

On my Excel worksheet I want to highlight all the cells in the range I158 to P193 that contain just three characters. I'm sure it shouldn't be too complicated but everything I've tried so far results in either all the cells being highlighted or none of them. 
I would be very grateful for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Select I158, Conditional Formating, New Rule, Use a formula to determine which cells to format, formula is =LEN(I158)=3, Choose your format then OK.
Conditional Formatting, Manage Rule, Select your rule, Applies to : =$I$158:$P$193